# Quickbooks PHP SDK Oauth2 callback parameters

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, quickbooks, quickbooks-online

I am building an app where I want multiple quickbooks connections. To do that I need to verify which user initiated which connection. To validate this I want to send some parameter to the callback URL called after the user authorizes the connection. How can we send some parameters to quickbooks that will be sent back to the call back URL?

**Edit**: Adding more details.

What I am trying to do is have the same user connect to multiple companies. However, I want to make sure to store the refresh tokens for all of them separately. To do that I want to check which company is connected to which one in my app.

So what I need to do is when I do the callback to my app after quickbooks authorization, I want to pass a parameter that can identify the company in my app for which the user authorized the quickbooks connection.

**Edit**: I found a solution. I am now using the state parameter to send the id that I want and use it in the callback to get that data.

Comment: Can you please add some code to your question?

Comment: @atymic I added some more details to the question. I can add the code for authorization and callback, but I am not very sure if that would be any help.